# How to customize default live session user desktop and environment on Kubuntu while remastering it?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, environment

I am chrooting into a kubuntu iso file with cubic and installing and modifying stuff I need to change for my custom live iso. But something I couldn't figure out is how to customize the default live  session's user environment, including its desktop, wallpaper, panels, shortcuts etc. There must be some template directory for this from where the live user session will be generated, but where is it and all the files to modify? I also couldn't find any tutorials or related information on this.

Comment: Found a solution. Here are the steps: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363773